# Using a long variable to store a char and printing it

Tags: c, printf, long-integer, type-mismatch, integer-promotion

I am storing a `char` in a `long` variable and trying to print it using `printf`.

```
long a = 'A';
printf("%c \n",a);
```

Considering *default argument promotions* the arguments get promoted to `int` but as `long` has higher rank than `int` it should not get promoted (or actually demoted) to `int`.

Now if it doesn't get promoted to `int` , in the printf statement isn't there a type mismatch as we are trying to print a `long` variable using `%c`. According to C standard this behavior should be undefined but the compiler is perfectly printing `A` as output without any error or warning. Why is it so ?

I am working on GCC codeblocks compiler.

Comment: Exactly what do you expect from "undefined behavior"?

Comment: Just because something is undefined behaviour doesn't mean it wont work.

Comment: So it means, it could or could not work but no one can be sure about that ? Right ?

Comment: And the constant `'A'` is actually an `int` and not a `char` in C.

Comment: Undefined behavior means that the behavior is not defined :)

Comment: @Andrew Henle  but we are storing that in a `long`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/6699433

Comment: Also, you're getting no warning because you do not compile with `-Wall`

Comment: UB, in your case, manifests by printing an `A`. Try `free(main)` and check that it prints an `A`.

Comment: When you jam the wrong size screw into a machine, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

Comment: It works because your machine is little-endian, helping printf() to read the little end correctly.  You will not have such luck on a big-endian machine.

Answer (score 2):

> According to C standard this behavior should be undefined but the compiler is perfectly printing A as output without any error or warning. Why is it so ?

Undefined behavior means that the behavior is not defined. That means that you cannot really expect it to behave in a certain way. Some things are more likely than others, but UB basically means that anything can happen.

Plus, the reason you don't get warnings is that you have not activated warnings.

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c 
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:14: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
    6 |     printf("%c \n",a);
      |             ~^     ~
      |              |     |
      |              int   long int
      |             %ld
```

I'd recommend compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Werror`

Note that the warning says `format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’` so passing an `int` to `%c` is perfectly fine. If you pass a `char` it will get promoted to `int`.

Related:

Promotions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/6699433

Undefined behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/6699433

Comment: if i try to print a `int` variable instead of  `long int` using `%c` will this be an undefined behavior or is it valid ?

Comment: @Noshiii This is valid. In fact, `%c` in `printf` expects an `int`. `char` is compatible to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII value of 'A' is casted and stored as a long number, the printf function casts it back to char as for %c, and prints back the 'A'

Actually, 'A' is just a number which is defined in a standardized way, so should be no problems.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `printf` is not required to do that cast

Comment: But anyway I think it implicitly casts.. C don't actually care about the data type unless for array and pointer stuff.. right?

Comment: For `%c`, `printf` attempts to get an `int` argument, and it then converts (or behaves as if it does) that to an `unsigned char` and prints that. But when a `long` is passed, `printf` is not expected to get that and cast it. Its behavior in OP’s attempt may be the same as if that were done, but there are various ways that result could come to be, and it is incorrect to say that `printf` converts a stored `long` to a character. Additionally, the C standard leaves the specification of character values quite loose.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your comments are often too good to be only comments. This as answer surely would help the OP at most as it shows what actually and apparently seems to be happen.